# How can I auto-generate a pulsar AvroSchema class from an existing model?

Tags: avro, apache-pulsar, genson, fastavro, python-pulsar

I'm running Apache Pulsar schemaless where the content is often changing. Now, there is some specific data for which I've written "data" classes (derived of [SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/), which doesn't really matter in this case). Since these models (data classes) are already available and will always lead the way, I wanted to use them for [Apache Pulsar](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/2.11.x/client-libraries-python/#schema-definition-reference) too.

I want to use `pulsar.schema.avro_schema.AvroSchema` over `JsonSchema` because the models are complex. I am very certain I'm not the first to run into this requirement.

I searched the internet but could not find a library, which

- copies the existing model (with all the fields and sub classes during run-time) into a `pulsar.schema.record.Record`
- and then populates the values of the existing instance  of the model into that Pulsar Schema Record.

I really want to avoid the manual process, which would look like this: I would specify the  `NewMetering_AVRO`, which is derived of the `NewMetering` model.

```
class NewMetering_AVRO(Record):
    id = Integer()
    speed = Float()
    light = Float()
```

Then create the producer.

```
producer = client.create_producer(
            topic='persistent://my_tenant/my_namespace/new_metering',
            schema=AvroSchema(NewMetering_AVRO),
            )
```

Right after I would have to build the object in a manual way and finally send the content.

```
new_metering_AVRO_record = NewMetering_AVRO()
new_metering_AVRO_record.id = uuid.uuid4()
new_metering_AVRO_record.speed = new_metering.speed
new_metering_AVRO_record.light = new_metering.light
producer.send(content=new_metering, partition_key=new_metering.id)
```

This manual process is error-prone and cumbersome. I really don't want to go down this road.

Anyone any hints on libraries or approaches? Otherwise I'm going to write my own public library.

Answer (score 0):

The only challenge is to translate the python class to a Avro schema in json format (schema definition). The Avro schema is then passed to Pulsar's AvroSchema class. There is a library for this: [How can I create an Avro schema from a python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75761216/how-can-i-create-an-avro-schema-from-a-python-class)

Not only does this Schema generator translates regular python classes. It can also translate pydantic and SQLModel classes (based on pydantic and sqlalchemy).