# How can I create an Avro schema from a python class?

Tags: python, avro, fastavro

How can I transform my simple python class like the following into a avro schema?

```
class Testo(SQLModel):
    name: str
    mea: int
```

This is the `Testo.schema()` output

```
{
    "title": "Testo",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "title": "Name",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "mea": {
            "title": "Mea",
            "type": "integer"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "name",
        "mea"
    ]
}
```

from here I would like to create an Avro record. This can be converted online on [konbert.com](https://konbert.com/convert/json/to/avro) (select JSON to AVRO Schema) and it results in the Avro schema below. (all valid despite the name field which should be "Testo" instead of "Record".)

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "title",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "type",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "properties.name.title",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "properties.name.type",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "properties.mea.title",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "properties.mea.type",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "required",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": "string"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyhow, if they can do it, there certainly must be a way to convert it with current python libraries. Which library can do a valid conversion (and also complex python models/classes?

If there is an opinion of that this is a wrong approach, that is also welcome - if - pointing out a better way how this translation process can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are a few libraries that aim to provide this kind of functionality:

1. [py-avro-schema](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/py-avro-schema) has support for generic Python classes
2. [dataclasses-avroschema](https://github.com/marcosschroh/dataclasses-avroschema) has support for dataclasses, pydantic models, and faust records
3. [pydantic-avro](https://github.com/godatadriven/pydantic-avro) requires your Python class to inherit from `pydantic.BaseModel`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a python library doing this, thus I've wrote it my self.

I loop over all the types and translate them one by one. I go recursive where there is a class reference in a field.

e.g. here example of the start of the method.

```
fields = []
        for field in model_class.__fields__.values():
            if issubclass(field.type_, SQLModel):
                # Recursively generate schema for nested models
                fields.append({"name": field.name, "type": self.create_field_array(self, field.type_)})
            elif field.type_ == str:
                fields.append({"name": field.name, "type": "string"})

... etc
```

For details on this method, check out our [repository fa-models for trading on GitHub](https://github.com/Freya-Alpha/fa-models/blob/main/famodels/generators). This class may translate regular python classes as well as pydantic, sqlalchemy and SQLModel classes. Help to increase the test cases for the library. We accept pull requests.